# How to fix 'Parsing email from modal' in Post request

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using windows 10 with python 3 and scrapy. Here is the site link that's i need to parsing email address

https://find.plasticsurgery.org/city/new-york

to getting individual people email it's need to click each time but i got a POST query from network section and developed a scrapy spider but still it's doesn't parsing any email.

```
url = "https://find.plasticsurgery.org/default.aspx/GetMemberInfo"

and the payload = {"memberId":"102971","searchId":"38066000"}
```

below my spider code

```
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from time import sleep
import scrapy
import csv
import json
import urllib

# urllib.parse.urlencode()

class PlasticsurgerySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'plasticsurgery'
    url = "https://find.plasticsurgery.org/default.aspx/GetMemberInfo"
    start_urls = [url]

    def parse(self, response):
        payload = {"memberId":"102971","searchId":"38066000"}
        yield Request(response.url, self.parse_page, method="POST", body=urllib.parse.urlencode(payload))
        # yield FormRequest.from_response(
        #             response=response,
        #             formdata=payload,
        #             callback=self.parse_page,
        #         )


    def parse_page(self, response):
        # data = json.loads(response.body)
        # print(data)
        # open_in_browser(response)
        email = response.xpath('//*[@class="btn btn-default card-btn email"]//@href').extract_first()
        email = email.replace('mailto:','')

        yield {
        'email':email
        }
```

end of the results i found just {'email': '#'}

we expect the result for email address such as {'email': any@anyemail.com}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you might wanna do to get the names and their email addresses. Feel free to use different search id's to get different results, as in `38078106` or `38066000` e.t.c.

```
import json
import scrapy

class PlasticsurgerySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'plasticsurgery'
    post_url = "https://find.plasticsurgery.org/default.aspx/GetMemberInfo"
    headers = {"content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
    start_urls = ["https://find.plasticsurgery.org/city/new-york"]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = set([item.split("('")[1].split("')")[0] for item in response.css("a[onclick^='showMemberInfo']::attr(onclick)").getall()])
        for item in items:
            payload = {'memberId':item,'searchId':'38066000'}
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.post_url,headers=self.headers,callback=self.parse_page, method="POST", body=json.dumps(payload))

    def parse_page(self,response):
        data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        for item in data:
            name = data[item]['MemberName'].strip()
            email = data[item]['Email']
            yield {"name":name,"email":email}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use actual headers?

```
headers = {
    'origin': 'https://find.plasticsurgery.org',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'referer': 'https://find.plasticsurgery.org/city/new-york',
    'authority': 'find.plasticsurgery.org',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'dnt': '1',
}

body= '{"searchId":"38074964","memberId":"20747"}'

yield Request('https://find.plasticsurgery.org/default.aspx/GetMemberInfo', headers=headers, body=body)
```